# Spring Boot mapping filter to /* even when using @WebFilter with url pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-boot

I defined a filter in my Spring Boot application (1.3.5) and annotated as below

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/api/*"}, description = "Create sessions only for API requests.")
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {
```

I want to use this filter to create session records in database for only API requests. However, I'm seeing this filter getting called for `/favicon.ico` request also. I annotated my main class with `@ServletComponentScan` as well. All classes are under sub packages of main class.

From the logs, I see `[/*]` is being mapped to filter. I can't get why.

```
[2016-06-09 22:39:34] [ INFO] [ost-startStop-1] [] [o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean ][configure                : 271] - Mapping filter: 'com.mycompany.package.filter.SessionFilter' to urls: [/api/*]
[2016-06-09 22:39:34] [ INFO] [ost-startStop-1] [] [o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean ][configure                : 258] - Mapping filter: 'sessionFilter' to: [/*]
```

I also registered following to enable Servlet 3.0 API.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer implements ServletContextInitializer {
```

I'm running in embedded tomcat.

**Update:**

When I added the `filterName` parameter `mySessionFilter`, the log looked like below. I also had to add `@Configuration` to Filter to get this.

```
[2016-06-14 18:55:58] [ INFO] [ost-startStop-1] [] [o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean ][configure                : 271] - Mapping filter: 'mySessionFilter' to urls: [/api/*]
[2016-06-14 18:55:58] [ INFO] [ost-startStop-1] [] [o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean ][configure                : 258] - Mapping filter: 'sessionFilter' to: [/*]
```

Comment: Could it possibly because annotation ServletComponentScan? Please remove it and try again and keep me aware of the result.

Comment: @GeminiKeith are you saying I should remove that altogether? Initially I did not had that and still faced the same problem. I moved the annotation to Filter class and still same problem.

Comment: Could we exclude specific pattern such as `/*.ico` in `WebFilter`? I mean we can exclude resources in web.xml if we use a traditional web war project.

Comment: I would not want to do that because that would be a huge list and so difficult to keep it up to date. I want to run this SessionFilter only when I am making a API request.

Comment: Do you also have a bean definition for the filter as it looks like the `@WebFilter` one is detected and a manually configured one through a `@Bean` method.

Comment: Are you sure SessionFilter is intercepting favicon.ico. Please use filterName to have some distinguished name  in @WebFilter and see if actual sessionFIlter is different from your filder

Comment: @M.Deinum I do not have bean definiition. I guess this one is detected as I implement Filter.

Comment: Why do you have a `ServletContextInitializer`? That isn't needed with Spring Boot (unless you deploy to a container and then you should extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. The first one looks like the one picked up from the ``@ServletComponentScan` the other a manually defined one. Is that the full filter declaration or do you by any change also have a `@Component` on it?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have `@ServletComponentScan` on SessionFilter. I do not have `Component` on it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I made an update with filter name, please take a look.

Comment: I finally found someone wrote a `SessionConfiguration` class with `@Configuration` annotiation and a bean in that class that returns `SessionFilter`. I deleted that class and also removed `@Configuration` on `SessionFilter`. Everything working as expected. That hint to add a `filterName` definitely helped. Thank you everyone.